# Запуск activity при уведомлении без запуска основной activity

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Создаётся и выводится на экран уведомление, при нажатии на которое запускается activity **NotificationActivity** (код немного упростил).

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("key_text", "notification text");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIconId)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, bigIconId))
            .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(message);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

Проблема в том, что при этом запускается и основная activity приложения **MainActivity**.

Как сделать так, чтобы запускалась только **NotificationActivity** при нажатии на уведомление?

Comment: Создайте свой ресивер (broadcast receiver) и в нем обрабатывайте,  что вам нужно открыть при получении определенного нотификейшена

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот эти флаги добавить к интенту. Тогда в момент нажатия будет запускаться только NotificationActivity. Но ничего не будет мешать запустить MainActivity из NotificationActivity.

```
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```